# Salesforce writing Test class of Future Method - Coverage 28%

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, force.com

I have a class where in I am trying to call a HTTP request. I have created a Mock Test and a Test class.

My Test class is successful with 28% code coverage but it fails in recognizing the call out methods I have used in my class Below is code

**My Class -**

```
public class PD_WelcomeMaroPost {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendEmailThroughMaro(string myInpEmail) {
        string successContacts = '';
        string failureContacts = '';

        List<Stripe_Subscripton__c> subsToUpdate = new List<Stripe_Subscripton__c>();
        //List<Case> newCase = new List<Case>();


        // SQL to fetch FBO who Joined Today
        list<Account> conts = new list<Account> ([SELECT Id, name, Email_FLP_com__c,
                                                (SELECT Id FROM Stripe_Subscriptons__r WHERE Start_Date__c= TODAY
                                                AND Status__c='active'
                                                AND Welcome_Email__C = false LIMIT 1)from account
                                                where ID IN (select Distributor__c from Stripe_Subscripton__c
                                                where Start_Date__c= TODAY AND Status__c='active'
                                                AND Welcome_Email__C = false)
                                                AND  Email_FLP_com__c != NULL LIMIT 100]);

        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>' + conts);
        overallEmail myEmail = new overallEmail();

        for(Account c : conts){
           string resultBodyGet = '';
            myEmail.email.campaign_id = 172;

            myEmail.email.contact.Email = c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            myEmail.email.contact.first_name = c.name;

            /**MAp<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
            tags.put('firstName', c.name);
            myEmail.email.tags = tags;**/
            system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(myEmail));


            try{
                String endpoint = 'http://api.maropost.com/accounts/1173/emails/deliver.json?auth_token=j-V4sx8ueUT7eKM8us_Cz5JqXBzoRrNS3p1lEZyPUPGcwWNoVNZpKQ';
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                req.setbody(JSON.serialize(myEmail));
                Http http = new Http();
                system.debug('Sending email');
                HTTPResponse response = http.send(req); 
                system.debug('sent email');
                 resultBodyGet = response.getBody();
                system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
                maroResponse myMaroResponse = new maroResponse();
                myMaroResponse = (maroResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, maroResponse.class);
                system.debug('#### myMaroResponse: ' + myMaroResponse);
                if(myMaroResponse.message == 'Email was sent successfully')
                   successContacts = successContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
                else
                    failureContacts = failureContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            }
            catch (exception e) {
                failureContacts = failureContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
                system.debug('#### Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());                
            }

            c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0].Welcome_Email__c = true;
            c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0].Welcome_Email_Sent_Date__c = system.today();
            subsToUpdate.add(c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0]);

        }

        Update subsToUpdate;

    }

    public class maroResponse {
        public string message {get;set;}
    }

    public class overallEmail {
        public emailJson email = new emailJson();
    }

    public class emailJson {
        public Integer campaign_id;

        public contactJson contact = new contactJson();
       //Public Map<String, String> tags;
    }

    public class contactJson {
        public string email;
        public string first_name;
    }

}
```

My MockTest Class- I have used this Mockclass to generate Mock response. The documentation does not have a test method thus used the same format

```
@isTest
Global class PD_WelcomeMaroPostMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    Global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        // Create a fake response
        // 

        //System.assertEquals(JSON.serialize(myEmail),req.getbody());

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"status":"success"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res; 
    }
}
```

This is my Test class - This is the class I have used for the response. I have a successful insert job but my HTTP responses are failing.

```
@IsTest
private class PD_WelcomeMaroPost_test {

    public class overallEmail {
        public emailJson email = new emailJson();
    }
    public class emailJson {
        public Integer campaign_id;

        public contactJson contact = new contactJson();
    }
    public class contactJson {
        public string email;
        public string first_name;
    }

    @IsTest
    private static void testemail() {

        overallEmail myEmail = new overallEmail();
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='Test' ;
        a.Email_FLP_com__c = 'test@nextsphere.com';
        insert a ; 

        Stripe_Subscripton__c s = new Stripe_Subscripton__c();

        // insert subscription --
        s.Distributor__c = a.Id;
        S.Welcome_Email__c = TRUE;
        S.Welcome_Email_Sent_Date__c = system.today();
        s.Subscription_Id__c = 'sub_9H0LLYFZkekdMA' ; 
        INSERT S;

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new PD_WelcomeMaroPostMock());
        String endpoint = 'http://api.maropost.com/accounts/1173/emails/deliver.json?auth_token=j-V4sx8ueUT7eKM8us_Cz5JqXBzoRrNS3p1lEZyPUPGcwWNoVNZpKQ';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setbody(JSON.serialize(myEmail));


        Test.startTest();

        PD_WelcomeMaroPost.sendEmailThroughMaro('test@nextsphere.com');

        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a Mock myself, I declare it inside the test start transaction:

```
Test.startTest();

Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

// Rest of test code here

Test.stopTest();
```

Also inside your test class you seem to only build the HTTP request and not send it try adding the below:

```
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) { } else { }
```